# Is possible to send multipart post fields as array in libcurl?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I can use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS set post body like 'a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3'.

When I try to populate Multipart params using curl_formadd it always return CURL_FORMADD_OPTION_TWICE, I see there was an option CURLFORM_ARRAY, but seems it's for options, not for multiple value field.

Is there any way to do this using curl API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[curl_formadd](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) is the (helpful) way to do multipart formposts with libcurl. You *can* also just create your own buffer and send it as a normal post, but that will require you to format everything yourself and I don't recommend that.

If you have problems with curl_formadd, it is probably better that you make an as small test as possible and ask about help with that. There are curl_formadd using examples on the curl web site.

Comment: Yes I'm already posted multipart data to server using:

    curl_formadd(&post, &last, 
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, name,
        CURLFORM_BUFFER, buffer_name,
        CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, buffer,
        CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, buffer_len,
        CURLFORM_END);

Seems that curl not support add same name part in curl_formadd.

Comment: No, its not that. curl doesn't care about the names you use for the part, the return code means it detected double use of _options_. Possibly you have an older libcurl with some bug in this code. Can't tell without more details and that is also not what this question nor stackoverflow in general are for...

Comment: I write a demo to post source file using a field twice, server just dump request 

https://gist.github.com/perlmonk/1f1d087fcf1dadbafd16

    `gcc form_test.cpp -lcurl -o form_test
    chmod +x form_test
    ./form_test`

And debug result here:

http://aaba.me/tmp/upload.png

Comment: Again, this is not the place. You can easily verify that curl does the right thing with this: "curl -F moo=moo -F moo=moo --trace-ascii - localhost". I know perfectly well that curl doesn't care about (duplicate) part names, I wrote the code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) I was wrong, I wrote bugs in my code. I'm porting cURL as an android java library, cURL now works Perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel Stenberg correct my fault.

It's easy to post array using curl_formadd

```
struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
char* buffer = "part body";
int len = strlen(buffer);
curl_formadd(&formpost,
           &lastptr,
           CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name[]",
           CURLFORM_BUFFER, "buffer",
           CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, buffer,
           CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, len,
           CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost,
           &lastptr,
           CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name[]",
           CURLFORM_BUFFER, "buffer",
           CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, buffer,
           CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, len,
           CURLFORM_END);
```